# How to sort axes in 2d categorical histogram to maximize clustering

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, histogram, data-science

I'm plotting 2d heatmap histograms of categorical data to help show and explain patterns in large datasets, and don't know a good approach for resonably efficiently sorting the values along each axis such that related values appear next to each other.

### Example

Using examples from [PyPI downloads logs](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/the-psf:pypi.downloads?pli=1), with just 4 projects, I can plot the histogram of project name vs file name:

[image: 2d Histogram of project vs filename with no sorting]

(Note, I stop at the 60 most common distinct values, and lump everything else into a single (other) column)

In this extreme example, each file name is associated with exactly one project, so the data would be much easier to understand if the x-values were re-ordered so that the all of the numpy files were next to each other, followed by the pandas files, etc...

In my situation, I can't guarantee if the x axis or the y axis will contain stronger category groups, so I'm hoping to find a solution that can sort along both axes.  I'm also dealing with histograms up to 60x60 values, and the time budget for doing this sorting is <500ms (ideally).

### Thoughts about correct solution

I think the answer lies in:

- creating a linkage map for all (x, y) combinations
- Running a hierarchical clustering on the linkage map
- Some form of sorting based on the clusters.

It wasn't clear to me how to reorder each axis using the hierarchical clusters.

Similar examples using correlation matrices effectively work off one-dimensional data, and translating this to two dimensions seems tricky.

### Current naive implementation

My current, somewhat poor, approach is to define an energy function for the table that takes the sum of the absolute differences of each value between each column and the next column:

```
def get_energy(values):
    np.abs(values[:, :-1] - values[:, 1:]).sum()
```

Then for each row, I calculate which columns I would have to swap to end up with the values in that row sorted (relative to the highest value in that row). Then for each swap, I calculate the energy of the table before and after the swap.  If the energy is lower, then I update my table with the swapped values, and continue.

Finally, I transpose the table, and repeat the above.

This approach is deeply flawed, as the naive swaps approach doesn't shift whole colums, and there is no collaboration between the order in each axis, so you end up with what I can only describe as fragmentation when the swaps for column 2 happen to disrupt the values in column 1:

[image: above histogram, but using the naive method]

An example using different data from the same dataset, comparing distribution name vs distribution version (Note I've got some axis normalization here, or Ubuntu would dominate everything!):

Unsorted:
[image: Distribution name vs Distribution version for pypi data, unsorted axes]

Using above method:
[image: Distribution name vs Distribution version for pypi data, sorted axes]

The current code I have looks like this: (Takes a pandas table, operates on numpy ndarrays):

```py
class Reorderer:

    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table = table.values
        self.rows = table.index.values
        self.cols = table.columns.values

    def get_frame(self):
        return pd.DataFrame(data=self.table, index=self.rows, columns=self.cols)

    def _energy(self, values):
        return np.abs(values[:, :-1] - values[:, 1:]).sum()

    def _get_proposals(self, row_num):
        row = self.table[row_num]
        swaps = row.argsort()[::-1]
        basis = swaps[0]
        for order, from_index in enumerate(swaps[1:], 1):
            if row[from_index] == 0:
                break
            to_index = basis + order
            if to_index >= len(self.cols):
                to_index = basis - order
            if from_index != to_index:
                yield (from_index, to_index)

    def reorder(self):
        initial_swaps = self.table[0].argsort()[::-1]
        self.table = self.table[:, initial_swaps]
        self.cols = self.cols[initial_swaps]
        for row_num in range(1, len(self.rows)):
            current_energy = self._energy(self.table[:row_num+1])

            for proposed_from, proposed_to in self._get_proposals(row_num):
                new_order = np.arange(len(self.cols))
                new_order[proposed_from] = proposed_to
                new_order[proposed_to] = proposed_from
                reordered = self.table[:, new_order]

                new_energy = self._energy(reordered[:row_num+1])
                if new_energy < current_energy:
                    self.table = reordered
                    self.cols = self.cols[new_order]
                    current_energy = new_energy
        return self.get_frame()
```

There must be a better approach to this.